# NgRx Store - TypeError: Cannot freeze

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

I am trying to make a simple login app with Angular, NgRx Store and Firebase. I created a login action which should login to firebase and store the credentials to the store.
Apparently I am doing something wrong. When I dispatch my action the firebase request is successfull, the credentials get returned but the store doesn't get updated and I get the following Error in the console

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot freeze
    at Function.freeze (<anonymous>)
    at freeze (ngrx-store.js:843)
    at ngrx-store.js:857
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at freeze (ngrx-store.js:845)
    at ngrx-store.js:857
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at freeze (ngrx-store.js:845)
    at ngrx-store.js:857
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
```

I know the state is immutable and it probably has something todo with this, but I can't figure out where my problem lies. Here is the code I use:

**State:**

```
export interface CoreState {
  readonly credentials: UserCredential
}

export const initialCoreState: CoreState = {
  credentials: {} as UserCredential
}
```

**actions:**

```
const signIn = createAction(
  `${actionPrefix} Sign In`,
  props<{ email: string, password: string }>()
);

const signInSuccess = createAction(
  `${actionPrefix} Sign In Success`,
  props<{ readonly userCredential: UserCredential }>()
);

const signInFailure = createAction(
  `${actionPrefix} Sign In Failure`,
  props<{ readonly error: string }>()
);

export const CoreActions = {
  signIn,
  signInSuccess,
  signInFailure
}
```

**Effects:**

```
@Injectable()
export class CoreEffects {
  signIn$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(CoreActions.signIn),
      switchMap(({ email, password }) =>
        this.authenticationService.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
          .pipe(
            map((userCredential: UserCredential) => {
                return CoreActions.signInSuccess({ userCredential })
              }
            ),
            catchError(error =>
              of(CoreActions.signInFailure({ error: error.statusText }))
            )
          )
      ),
    )
  );

  constructor(
    private readonly actions$: Actions,
    private readonly authenticationService: AuthenticationService
  ) {}
}
```

**Reducer:**

```
export const coreReducer = createReducer<CoreState>(
  initialCoreState,

  on(CoreActions.signInSuccess, (state, { userCredential }) => {
    console.log('Inside Reducer');
    return {
      ...state,
      credentials: userCredential
    }
  })
```

)

I found out that when I use `Object.freeze(userCredentials)` before passing it from effects into `signInSucess` and then use `Object.freeze(userCredentials)` again before assigning it in the reducer it works. But this seems really weird to me. Maybe someone can help me out and explain or point out where my mistake lies. Thanks!

Edit: Added AuthenticationService and App Component

**AuthenticationService**

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthenticationService {

  constructor(private readonly angularFireAuth: AngularFireAuth) { }

  signOut(): Observable<void> {
    return from(this.angularFireAuth.signOut());
  }

  createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: string, password: string): Observable<UserCredential> {
    return from(this.angularFireAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password));
  }

  signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: string, password: string): Observable<UserCredential> {
    return from(this.angularFireAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password));
  }
}
```

**App Component**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'firebase-auth';

  constructor(private readonly store: Store) {}

  onClick(): void {
    const email = 'test@test.com';
    const password = '123456';
    this.store.dispatch(CoreActions.signIn({ email, password }))
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Helvetios, have you found a solution for this issue? Your workaround using `Object.freeze` also works for me, but as you say it doesn't seem to be the right way to do things....

Comment: Btw I'm doing exactly the same as you, authentication with AngularFireAuth

Comment: @Spray'n'Pray Sadly no, I currently implemented it with Object.freeze even though it seems kind of ugly

Comment: I found a way that IMO is a bit cleaner. I think the problem is, that the object you dispatch in the effect comes from firebase and firebase will somehow mutate it on the way, which is what makes ngrx complain. So what I did was I wrote this small function: `export const deepCopy = <T>(obj: T): T => JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));` and in the effect I write: `signedUpUser({ credentials: deepCopy(credentials) })`. This works for me and I don't have to use `Object.freeze` in any other part of the application

Comment: @Spray'n'Pray Thank you for sharing! This was my thought too but I did not further investigate. This seems to be a bit better than Object.freeze

Answer (score 0):

The code you shared seems fine to me.
My guess is that the state is changed in a component (or maybe the service), after it's retrieved via a selector.

Comment: I also added my AuthService and AppComponent but I still can't figure out what might cause the error or what changes the state